# Check if a string contains a column value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to retrieve information on multiple accounts by finding every account contained in a string. I have account numbers `43000-000-00`, `40000-100-00`, and `45075-200-00`, all of which can be found in the `account` column.

`SELECT * FROM records WHERE CHARINDEX('43000-000-00', account)` works fine, however augmenting the string with new characters or swapping the account string with the column will not longer yield results. Is there any way I can detect every account in `'43000-000-00, 40000-100-00, 45075-200-00'` or another similarly formatted string?

EDIT: the accounts follow XXXXX-XXX-XX format, with a few cases where letters are used

Comment: You have to use `LIKE`. There must be thousands of pages about this. For example: `WHERE account LIKE '40000-%'`, or `WHERE account LIKE '40000-___-__'` (you don't specify the exact format you look for). `%` replaces any number of characters and `_` just one.

Comment: `with a few cases where letters are used`, in any place and any amount? So can `AAAAA-AAA-AA` be a valid account number? You need to give more details.

Comment: @Andrew it theoretically could, but the only instances thus far where letters are used are in the last two segments

Comment: Oh, so you need to first split by `,` and then match that format. What an ugly design.... Does that have to be done in SQL? Are you filtering records depending on a condition in this multiple-account field? Please, try to explain the whole thing; every time you give further details which make previous help effort useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
where account like '43000-000-00%' or
      account like '40000-100-00%' or
      account like '45075-200-00%'
```

If these are exact matches, use `in`:

```
where account in ('43000-000-00', '40000-100-00%', '45075-200-00')
```

If you actually want to pass in a string with commas, you need to investigate `string_split()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't been too specific. Is the first digit of the of the second number tuple the only one changing? If so, this will do the job:

```
SELECT * 
FROM records 
WHERE account like '40000-[0-9]00-00'
```

or use [0-2] instead of [0-9] if you only care about the three values you mentioned

General aplhanumeric version as per comment:

```
SELECT * 
FROM records 
WHERE account like '[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]-[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]-[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]'
```

Comment: i used poor examples, sorry! the majority of accounts are numeric, with some alphanumeric instances, but all follow the XXXXX-XXX-XX format.

Comment: alright, in place of every X put a [0-9a-zA-Z] in the like

Comment: will that help me? i need to be able to detect every account in a string that contains multiple accounts... it looks like your answer will show me every single account that follows the account format.

Comment: Can you please update your question, probably with examples, to make what you want clear? How does an account contain other accounts? What other columns are there in your table that show this kind of connection?